# Pandas - rolling sum of last N elements with condition

Tags: pandas

The following line:

```
df['moment'] = df.groupby('team').P.apply(lambda x : x.rolling(5).sum().fillna(0))
```

Generates the following dataframe, with a new column 'moment', which has the rolling sum of the past 5 'P' points:

---

```
          round          team  P   GP   GC   moment
0            1       Flamengo  0  0.0  1.0   0.0
1            2       Flamengo  0  0.0  3.0   0.0
2            3       Flamengo  3  1.0  0.0   0.0
3            4       Flamengo  1  1.0  1.0   0.0
4            5       Flamengo  1  1.0  1.0   5.0
5            6       Flamengo  3  1.0  0.0   8.0
6            7       Flamengo  3  5.0  3.0  11.0
7            8       Flamengo  3  2.0  1.0  11.0
8            9       Flamengo  3  2.0  1.0  13.0
9           10       Flamengo  0  0.0  2.0  12.0
10          11       Flamengo  3  2.0  1.0  12.0
11          12       Flamengo  1  1.0  1.0  10.0
12          13       Flamengo  3  3.0  1.0  10.0
13          14       Flamengo  3  3.0  0.0  10.0
14          15       Flamengo  3  2.0  1.0  13.0
15          16       Flamengo  1  1.0  1.0  11.0
16          17       Flamengo  3  5.0  1.0  13.0
17          18       Flamengo  1  2.0  2.0  11.0
18          19       Flamengo  0  1.0  4.0   8.0
19          20       Flamengo  0  0.0  4.0   5.0
```

---

But I need to apply the sum of the last 4, 3, 2 and 1 'P' as well, `up to index 4`, when we haven't reached N=5 yet. At the moment it is 0, which is wrong...

how do I tweak the code above in order to achieve this?

---

Desired result:

```
          round          team  P   GP   GC   moment
0            1       Flamengo  0  0.0  1.0   0.0
1            2       Flamengo  0  0.0  3.0   0.0
2            3       Flamengo  3  1.0  0.0   3.0
3            4       Flamengo  1  1.0  1.0   4.0
4            5       Flamengo  1  1.0  1.0   5.0
5            6       Flamengo  3  1.0  0.0   8.0
6            7       Flamengo  3  5.0  3.0  11.0
7            8       Flamengo  3  2.0  1.0  11.0
8            9       Flamengo  3  2.0  1.0  13.0
9           10       Flamengo  0  0.0  2.0  12.0
10          11       Flamengo  3  2.0  1.0  12.0
11          12       Flamengo  1  1.0  1.0  10.0
12          13       Flamengo  3  3.0  1.0  10.0
13          14       Flamengo  3  3.0  0.0  10.0
14          15       Flamengo  3  2.0  1.0  13.0
15          16       Flamengo  1  1.0  1.0  11.0
16          17       Flamengo  3  5.0  1.0  13.0
17          18       Flamengo  1  2.0  2.0  11.0
18          19       Flamengo  0  1.0  4.0   8.0
19          20       Flamengo  0  0.0  4.0   5.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a minimum number of periods. The default `None` sets `min_periods=window` which in this case is 5. See [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).

```
df['moment'] = df.groupby('team').P.apply(lambda x : x.rolling(5, min_periods=1).sum().fillna(0))
```

`.rolling(5, 1)`works also at a loss of readability.

Comment: `fillna(0)` is redundant with `min_periods=1`.

Comment: A good point. I was keeping it in case there were NAs in the data in rows 20 on. Although unless there are 5 NAs in a row then it won't matter. So in **most** cases it will be redundant.

Comment: No, you were right to include it. I didn't account for that possibility.

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot. But I need to add one more column to groupby criteria. I tried df.groupby(['team', 'captain']), but it's throwing error. Also tried df.groupby([['team', 'captain']]) and that results in dimension error.